# Undefined valor en el atributo Data Vanilla-javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, dataset

me encuentro realizando una función que hace la delegación de eventos y me recibe ciertos parámetros de los cuales quiero que me muestre el valor de su atributo DATA del elemento HTML

Les voy a enseñar mi código

#### HTML

```
<a class="delete" data-delete="1">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="2">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="3">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="4">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="5">Delete</a>
```

#### jAVASCRIPT

```
function delegacionEvento(elemento, atributo, valorAtributo) {
    elemento.addEventListener('click', e => {
        //OBTENER EL ATRIBUTO DE CLASS Y QUE SEA IGUAL A 'delete'
        if (e.target.getAttribute(atributo) == valorAtributo) {
                //GUARDAR EL VALOR DEL ATRIBUTO DATA EN LA VARIABLE
                var valor = e.target.dataset.Valoratributo;
                console.log(valor); //Respuesta undefined
        }//End if
    });
}//End método delegacionEvento
```

Y así llamo la función pasandole los parámetros

```
delegacionEvento(loadSong, 'class', 'delete');
```

El resultado que obtengo es `undefined`

Alguien me podría ayudar a resolver mi problema. Gracias

Comment: El parámetro `loadSong` a que hace referencia?

Comment: @para obtener el atributo deberías utilizar **data-delete** en vez de **delete** saludos

Comment: Hola victor el parámetro `loadSong` es el elemento padre que contiene el bloque que están los `<a>`

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar corchetes `[]` para llamar al atributo.  Ademas tenias un typo en `valorAtributo`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
function delegacionEvento(elemento, atributo, valorAtributo) {
    elemento.addEventListener('click', e => {
        //OBTENER EL ATRIBUTO DE CLASS Y QUE SEA IGUAL A 'delete'
        if (e.target.getAttribute(atributo) == valorAtributo) {
                //GUARDAR EL VALOR DEL ATRIBUTO DATA EN LA VARIABLE
                var valor = e.target.dataset[valorAtributo];
                console.log(valor); //Respuesta undefined
        }//End if
    });
}//End método delegacionEvento

var loadSong = document.getElementsByClassName('delete')[0];

delegacionEvento(loadSong, 'class', 'delete');
```

```html
<a class="delete" data-delete="1">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="2">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="3">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="4">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="5">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Muchar gracias Alan, por tu respuesta, la tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Al utilizar `dataset` te arroja un objeto y tienes que entrar a su valor por medio de la clave utilizando `[]`, además de que estás pasando mal el parámetro `valorAtributo`, cuálquier duda hazla saber.

```js
function delegacionEvento(elemento, atributo, valorAtributo) {
    elemento.addEventListener('click', e => {
        //OBTENER EL ATRIBUTO DE CLASS Y QUE SEA IGUAL A 'delete'
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute(atributo))
        if (e.target.getAttribute(atributo) == valorAtributo) {
                //GUARDAR EL VALOR DEL ATRIBUTO DATA EN LA VARIABLE
                console.log(e.target.dataset[valorAtributo]);
                //var valor = e.target.dataset.valorAtributo;
                var valor = e.target.dataset[valorAtributo];
                console.log(valor); //Respuesta undefined
        }//End if
    });
}

delegacionEvento(document.querySelectorAll('a')[0],'class', 'delete');
```

```html
<a class="delete" data-delete="1">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="2">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="3">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="4">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" data-delete="5">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, esa fue mi solución abrir los corchetes y pasar ValorAtributo